# Get BSD file descriptor from OSX CoreServices objects

Tags: macos, bsd, core-services

I am new to OSX user space development. I've read documentation and googled before asking, but still have no clue about the following.

If i am to use CoreServices framework to work with files (FSRef, Forks, URLs, etc.) will i be able to get a raw BSD file descriptor (plain int)? If yes, then how can i do that? The thing is, i want to learn to program with OSX frameworks, but the actual task at hand *will* require BSD file descriptor later.

Inso.

Comment: There's a lot of confusion here. FSRef, FSSpec, CFURL, etc. are not handles to open files; they're ways of specifying a file on disk, like a pathname. There is no associated file descriptor to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is really no way to do this. Oh well.